# Error after zip in python

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to run the following python code.

```
import numpy as np

recarr = np.zeros((2,), dtype=('i4,f4,a10'))

col1 = np.arange(1,3)
col2 = np.arange(4,6, dtype=np.float32)
col3 = ['Man', 'Woman']

tmp = zip(col1, col2, col3)
recarr[:] = tmp
```

But I had the following error message.

```
File "<ipython-input-55-0c1735078108>", line 1, in <module>
recarr[:] = tmp
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: please explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Are you on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am on Python 3.

Comment: I just wanted to save the tuple (after zip) into the recarr format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zip` function returns an iterator. To properly assign it to a slice you must materialize the iterator:

```
>>> recarr[:] = list(tmp)
>>> recarr
array([(1,  4., b'Man'), (2,  5., b'Woman')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', 'S10')])
```

Note, if you don't want to materialize the iterator into a wasteful intermediate data-structure, you can use `np.fromiter`:

```
>>> recarr = np.fromiter(tmp, dtype=('i4,f4,a10'), count=2)
>>> recarr
array([(1,  4., b'Man'), (2,  5., b'Woman')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', 'S10')])
>>>
```

Note, I passed the `count` argument, which is optional, but if you *can* provide a `count` argument, it will make this constructor much more efficient.